# Time series and sequence analysis in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Lets say I have the following data in MongoDB:

```js
{
  timePeriod: 1,
  foo: 1,
  bar: 6,
  baz: 8
},
  {
  timePeriod: 2,
  foo: 7,
  bar: 5,
  baz: 2
},
  {
  timePeriod: 3,
  foo: 3,
  bar: 6,
  baz: 9
},
  {
  timePeriod: 4,
  foo: 4,
  bar: 5,
  baz: 4
},
  {
  timePeriod: 5,
  foo: 0,
  bar: 8,
  baz: 1
},
  {
  timePeriod: 6,
  foo: 6,
  bar: 1,
  baz: 0
},
```

After sorting the objects by timePeriod, I am interested in examining sequences that appear between each sorted object, and attaching this sequence to the original data.

So between timePeriod 1 and timePeriod 3, the sequence of foo is 1, 7, 3, and between time Period 4 and timePeriod 6, the sequence of foo is 4, 0, 6.

First thing - would anyone know a way to do this as a MongoDB. It seems straightforward (and easy to do with Python/Pandas, but I don't know MongoDB well enough. I am expecting the the end result of the query to look like the code below.

Second thing - if I wanted to do some operations on this sequence I get out of the query(like find out the absolute distance between each number in the sequence and the next, so 1, 7, 3 becomes 6, 4) is that possible to do in MongoDB?

```js
{
  timePeriod: 1,
  foo: 1,
  bar: 6,
  baz: 8,
  fooSeqFromThisTimeOnwards: [1, 7, 3]
},
  {
  timePeriod: 2,
  foo: 7,
  bar: 5,
  baz: 2,
  fooSeqFromThisTimeOnwards: [7, 3, 4]
},
  {
  timePeriod: 3,
  foo: 3,
  bar: 6,
  baz: 9,
  fooSeqFromThisTimeOnwards: [3, 4, 0]
},
  {
  timePeriod: 4,
  foo: 4,
  bar: 5,
  baz: 4,
  fooSeqFromThisTimeOnwards: [4, 0, 6]
},
  {
  timePeriod: 5,
  foo: 0,
  bar: 8,
  baz: 1,
  fooSeqFromThisTimeOnwards: [0, 6, nan]
},
  {
  timePeriod: 6,
  foo: 6,
  bar: 1,
  baz: 0,
  fooSeqFromThisTimeOnwards: [6, nan, nan]
},
```

*UPDATE:* Just a quick addendum to this - the more I look into this, it seems it is just not possible to do this (??) - only solution I can think of is using some kind of forEach thing, iterate and get the next n foo values that are $gt current timePeriod, and attach those values to the object I am at in the iteration. Then I can group by sequences and return similar sequence objects.

But that approach seems really expensive, like if I have a web service that makes a lot of requests for different sized sequences. So is it better to just have sequences hard coded into the original data and then just regex query this to pick sequences with n elements when needed? But if I do that, my original data seems to have some redundancy in it and becomes a lot bigger.

Just not really sure of the best approach here...